# ruby pagination with will_paginate with mongo db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, will-paginate

I read the will_paginate tutorial and the result was

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x007f7c09428d80>
```

---

```
class   ServicesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @services = Service.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
        @organs = Admin::Organ.all

    end

    def show
        @service = Service.where(permalink: params[:permalink]).first       
    end
end
```

---

```
<%= will_paginate @services %>
```

Does someone have an idea about this error?

Comment: Have you checked **@services** is **not nil** ?

Comment: This returns the data registered in other parts of the system that need to seek the services , but in this case gives this error with Mongoid

Answer (score 0):

can you do change like this in your index method

```
def index
  @organs = Admin::Organ.all
  @services = Service.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```